# Async/await not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get Number 1 to console.log first but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
let timer = function(time, message) {
    setTimeout((time) => {
        console.log(`ALERT: ${message}`);
    }, time);
  //return time;
}

const asyncDemo = async function asyncDemo(time, message) {
    try {
        var time1 = await timer(3000, "Number 1");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Critical error!");
    }
    try {
        var time2 = await timer(1000, "Number 2");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Critical error!");
    }
}

asyncDemo();
```

Comment: Wouldn't your `timer()` function need to return a promise, which you would then resolve from inside the timeout callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansync/Await depends on promises to work. So your function needs to return a promise. For instance:

```
let timer = function(time, message) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            setTimeout((time) => {
                console.log(`ALERT: ${message}`);
                resolve()
            }, time);

    }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. You just put it all into perspective.

Comment: or, in a one liner `let timer = (time, message) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time, \`ALERT: ${message}\`)).then(console.log);`